# Xpath Getting All Nodes that Have an Attribute that Matches Another Node

Tags: xpath

I want to find all nodes that have an attribute with a value that is the same as some other item. I have the item that should be used to do the lookup and the attribute that should be compared. Is this possible?

```
<base src="www.placeholder.com"></base>
<parent src="www.test.com">
   <child name="child1" src="www.test.com"></child>
   <child name="child2" src="www.placeholder.com"></child>
   <child name="child3" src="www.test.com"></child>
</parent>
```

I want to write an xpath query that gets all nodes that have the same source as the base node (child2) but I can't hard code www.placeholder.com into my xpath query.

Comment: Can you provide a piece of sample HTML or XML?

Comment: Yes that's possible (assuming that I understand the description correctly).

Comment: This question needs more context i.e sample XML and corresponding expected output elements, for someone to be able to post a real answer

Comment: Updated to try to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the entire XML snippet is wrapped in a root element, say `<root>` for example, (otherwise it isn't well-formed XML), you can then use the following XPath expression :

```
//*[@src = /root/base/@src]
```

The result is all elements, where `src` attribute equals `base` element's `src`, including the `base` element itself :

```
<base src="www.placeholder.com"/>

<child name="child2" src="www.placeholder.com"/>
```

Live demo example can be run [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/6e8daf9da7d92079594fb0f81bd639b1)

Comment: Sweet. I could have sworn I tried using this exactly but I'll take a run at it again and mark this as the answer if it works out.

Comment: It'll work unless you've not shown sufficiently representative context.